# Why does my simple Firefox extension now refuse to run?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

It pains me to ask such a basic question, but I'm at my wits' end.

### Situation

- I'm working on a 32-bit Windows 7 machine, running Firefox 34.0.5.
- I have a trivial Firefox extension in directory `C:\Projects\CloudGem\plugin`.
  The file structure is as follows:

  [image: CloudGem directory structure]
- All other plugins, excepting some FF developer plugins, are disabled.
- All files are confirmed UTF-8 encoded.

### File Contents

The contents of both instances of `cloudgem.js` are:

```
window.addEventListener( "load", function() {
    setInterval( function() {
        console.log( "Cloudgem service started (2)." );
    }, 2000 );
}, false );

console.log( "Cloudgem service started (1)." );
```

The contents of `cloudgem.xul` are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE overlay>

<overlay id="cgem-scriptmount" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
    <script type="application/x-javascript" src="cloudgem.js" />
</overlay>
```

The contents of `chrome.manifest` are:

```
# Content definitions.

content      cloudgem      chrome/content/


# Overlays.

overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://cloudgem/content/cloudgem.xul
```

The contents of `install.rdf` are:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
    <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
        <em:id>cloudgem@cloudgem.net</em:id>
        <em:version>1.0</em:version>
        <em:type>2</em:type>

        <!-- Target application this extension can install into, with minimum and maximum supported versions. -->
        <em:targetApplication>
            <Description>
                <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
                <em:minVersion>1.5</em:minVersion>
                <em:maxVersion>34.0.*</em:maxVersion>
            </Description>
        </em:targetApplication>

        <!-- Front end metadata. -->
        <em:name>CloudGem</em:name>
        <em:description>A description of GloudGem.</em:description>
        <em:creator>Me</em:creator>
        <em:homepageURL>http://cloudgem.net/</em:homepageURL>
    </Description>
</RDF>
```

The contents of `cloudgem@cloudgem.net` are:

```
C:\Projects\CloudGem\plugin\
```

A duplicate copy of this file exists in the `extensions` folder of my Firefox developer profile.

### What Happens

- Firefox appears to load the extension without issue. It appears in the list of active plugins. All the metadata is correct.
- Running `chrome://cloudgem/content/cloudgem.xul` in the address bar runs the script as expected, generating messages on the console.
- Roughly a month ago I created another extension with virtually identical structure. It loaded and the scripts executed as expected.
- The problem now is that the **code will not run.**  >____<  When Firefox starts up, it does absolutely nothing. No errors. No messages on the console. It just sits there like a dumb fox, not running my code. Moreover, my previous extensions that worked as of a month ago have also inexplicably stopped running at startup.

### What I've Already Tried

- Creating a brand new developer profile and installing the plugin there. Same result.
- Changing the console output calls to `dump()` calls, throwing exceptions, changing the window title, etc. Same result.
- Changing the names of the files. Same result.
- Migrating to a different machine (this time running Windows XP). Same result.
- Duplicating the `cloudgem.js` code in the `components` folder and running it as script in a XUL overlay. This is a hack, in response to the fact that FF wasn't running the code in the `components` folder. Neither instance of the code runs.

As I say, I'm completely out of ideas. I have no idea why this isn't running at browser startup. The only changes on my system between now and a month ago when the code worked is some routine updates to my OS, Firefox, and virus checker. Disabling the "web shield" of my virus checker (Avast) doesn't remedy the problem, and the virus checker isn't making any discernible noise about the plugin.

Can anyone suggest a solution? I've run up and down the MDN articles and found nothing.

Much thanks in advance.

Comment: The `@` in filename of `cloudgem@cloudgem.net` is bad I'm pretty sure so remove that fore sure. Let me know if that fixes things, if not Ill read more into it. Nice work creating the question. :) Also do you have a github? Can you upload this as a repo that would help me show you what things i tried in debugging it

Comment: @Noitidart: Thanks for your help. I've uploaded all the files to https://github.com/syonidv/lazy-fox. Windows doesn't have a problem with the `@` in the filename. It may just be a Unix/Linux thing. The MDN article on creating FF extensions actually recommends projectname@yourdomain.whatever as a unique ID for your plugin. Several of the other plugins I use (such as Firebug) also use this convention.

Comment: Ill take a look in the middle of some important work. They recommend that as an ID but not as file names. I'm guessing it didn't fix it though huh?

Comment: @Noitidart: I'll give it a go and let you know. ;) If I don't reply in a few minutes, assume it didn't work.

Comment: @COTO Are you sure the extension is not loaded? Are you looking at the right console? Follow these two steps 1) go to about:config in the address bar, and look for logLevel (loop.debug.loglevel to be precise), change that to "all".  2) check browser console "ctrl+shift+j" (or Hamburger Menu -> Developer -> Browser Console). Nothing is printed there? You can also try to change last parameter addEventListener to true, to useCapture.

Comment: @lpiepiora: That's it! The stupid thing wasn't actually printing the messages on the console, even though it did when I directly loaded the .xul file in the browser. Post your comment as an answer, and I'll give you the bounty. Thanks. :D

Comment: @COTO thanks. I did. I will also later update it to improve the quality (add some screenshots), because I think it's a more generic question: How to check output of Firefox plugins, which clearly is not so obvious ;)

Comment: @lpiepiora: It's also not the least bit obvious that the browser console isn't the same thing as the debug console in the inspection window. The messages appear in the former but not the latter. I think Mozilla screwed the pooch somewhere in their design. But at least I can get some reasonable output now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking at a wrong console. Add-ons output information to the Browser Console.The more general question is how to see output on the Browser Console.

It's not so obvious, but you can do it following these two steps.

1) In the location bar type in `about:config`, and look for `loop.debug.loglevel`, change the value to `all` to be sure all output is logged.

[image: Step1]

You may need to restart your browser.

2) Open Browser Console, by either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> or Hamburger Menu -> Developer -> Browser Console.

[image: Developer Console]

The messages should be printed there.

[image: Messages]